# in Oracle, how can i read a large blob as a text document

Tags: java, oracle, text, groovy, blob

I have a BLOB which actually contains text from a few hundreds chars to 20K+ chars.  I am given this (I know it should be a CLOB, but not my choice). I need to be able to get the entire text document.  The closest I've come is this:

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(blob_data,2000,1)) from my_table where id = 'id_value'; --get up to 2000
```

I can't get past 2000 at a time, though I guess I can get the size (using dbms_lob.getlength) and get 2000 at a time and put it together.  Seems like there should be a better answer.  Does anyone have a better way?

Comment: do you need it just for display purposes in SQL*Plus, or to use within a stored procedure/function, or to retrieve the data to an external application?

Comment: Is you limited to one select only? Why not use [`DBMS_LOB.ConvertToClob()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i1020356)? What is a final purpose of that extraction?

Comment: I just need this for viewing purposes for support personnel via a web app.
I will check out the conversion call - thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what worked here:
[Getting Blob information via Groovy](http://josies.blogspot.com/2012/04/asserting-blob-information-from.html)

Here's my Groovy code:

```
String sqlQuery = "select EVENT_MSG_DATA as blob from AUDIT_EVENT where AUDIT_EVENT_ID = '" + auditEventId + "'";
def blob = sql.firstRow(sqlQuery).blob;
String messageContents = new String(blob.getBytes(1,(int)blob.length()));
return messageContents;
```

Way easier than other possibilities.  No idea why it's so hard to find this solution.  Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove the conversion to VARCHAR2, which cause the problem ([Data Types with Different Maximum Sizes in PL/SQL and SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#CHDEDFJE)).

Then,

from SQL*Plus, define the column to show enough char (column ... format a*n*), possibly set LONG size ([COLUMN format, in Character section](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12013.htm#BACHCABF)) then SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE *n*

from PL/SQL, DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(*n*)

from OCI, you need to allocate a locator then bind its address, it shouldn't have a size limit

all 3 with *n* between 2000 and 1000000.

Comment: Thanks - I will give this a try, though I admit I'm not clear on all this. Can you give actual steps for Oracle DB?